# LEFT JOIN in BigQuery with row number function

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join, window-functions, row-number

I'm trying to do below join between BQ-data and data from csv file in our sandbox but I get a syntax error saying "Expected ")" but got keyword ON at [45:1]" which is the row where the ON is happening. I can't understand why and it could be because I havn't written that many of them. It might not be the row number function that messes it up. Could someone support me in evaluating it?

```
SELECT 
paymentsDB.*,
bq.*


FROM (
    
SELECT 
string_field_0 AS orderId_payments,
string_field_1 as type,
string_field_2 as status

FROM `xxxx-xxxx.xxxx_xxxxxx_1aug2021`

) paymentsDB

LEFT JOIN 

( SELECT
       (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq, 
        hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
        hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
        hits.page.pagePath as page, 
        hitnumber AS hitnumber 

    FROM (SELECT Row_number()
        OVER( PARTITION BY (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) 
        ORDER BY hitnumber DESC)RN,
        (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq, 
        hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
        hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
        hits.page.pagePath as page, 
        hitnumber AS hitnumber 

    FROM `xxxx-xxxxx.ga_sessions_*` t,

         UNNEST(HITS) as hits 
         WHERE (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 8) = 'se'
         AND (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 4) = 'soffadirekt'
         AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210801' AND '20210802'
         AND RN = 1

) bq

ON paymentsDB.orderId_payments = bq.orderId_bq
```

So an example on how I want to look is below table. I want to match the latest hitnumbers with the status I have in paymentsDB with the same orderId:

| orderId_payments | type | status | orderId_bq, | event_action | page | hitnumber | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | debit | success | 12345 | backend trx | /backend-trx | 40 | 1 |
| 56778 | debit | error | 56778 | iframe load | /payments | 42 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing a right parenthesis. I added a comment where I would add the right parenthesis.

```
( SELECT
   (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq, 
    hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
    hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
    hits.page.pagePath as page, 
    hitnumber AS hitnumber 

FROM (SELECT Row_number()
    OVER( PARTITION BY (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) 
    ORDER BY hitnumber DESC)RN,
    (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq, 
    hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
    hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
    hits.page.pagePath as page, 
    hitnumber AS hitnumber 

    FROM `xxxx-xxxxx.ga_sessions_*` t,

         UNNEST(HITS) as hits 
         WHERE (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 8) = 'se'
         AND (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 4) = 'soffadirekt'
         AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210801' AND '20210802'
         AND RN = 1
    ) --I added this                                                  
)bq
```

You should double check all your parenthesis to make sure they follow your logic if this doesn't fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I couldnt see that. I'm having problem with it not regognizing 't' - which is the alias I'm giving to the GA-sessions-source. I don't see why - is it because the custom dimension-subquery collides with my row number function? That I have to have a CTE on it's own for the row number-function?

Comment: I solved that as well - by just selecting the columns by their aliases before the row number-function instead of with the whole unnesting